# Integrated terminal (VSCode) not recognizing commands that work in standalone Terminal app

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, integrated-terminal-window

VSCode integrated terminal keeps giving me "command not found" errors even though running the same command in Terminal app works.

Fortunately, git commands work in the VSCode integrated terminal, but not "npm run start:dev" or "brew-v" etc

I get the "command no found" error in the VSCode integrated terminal when I type something like `brew -v`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOsEV.png)

I'm also using Pop OS on a Linux machine if that makes any difference. When I type `echo $SHELL` I [updated](https://www.shanebart.com/set-default-vscode-terminal/) my default terminal to be the same as my Terminal app, as well. But I think it has something to do with default integrated terminal settings not configured / set up properly to look in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the PATH variable, Opening a new integrated terminal in VSCode and running the command `echo $PATH`. Then compare the output with the PATH variable in your Terminal app by running the same command there `echo $PATH`, and then check if there are any differences.

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment

Comment: It was helpful to see that my outputs of `echo $PATH` were different, but when looking up how to change my PATH in VSCode, I think it was for a different version of VSCode as in I wasn't able to get it to work